# PHP And JS Code Not Executed

Tags: php, javascript

i Have This PHP and JS Code on my web page.

```
<?php
include 'connect1.php';
$query = "SELECT URL FROM remontee_nlf ORDER BY URL ASC";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());;
$counter = 0;
// write the values from the database into the javascript array
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";
    echo "this.styleListArray = new Array();";
    if ($result) {
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo("this.nameArray[" . $counter . "] = '" . $row['URL'] . ", " .          $row['user_fname'] . "';"); // displays 'lname, fname'
            $counter += 1;
        }
    }
echo("</script>");

?>
```

The Problem is that when i execute the page containing the code, a part of this code doesn't get executed and it just shows on the page as a simple text :

```
"); echo "this.styleListArray = new Array();"; if ($result) { while($row =   mysql_fetch_array($result)) { echo("this.nameArray[" . $counter . "] = '" . $row['URL'] . ", " . $row['user_fname'] . "';"); // displays 'lname, fname' $counter += 1; } } echo(""); ?>
```

I tried to figure it out, but i couldn't get it, if you can help brothers, that would be wonderful.

Comment: The JS code is *meant* to be output as text. Are you saying the PHP is also?

Comment: Id strongly recommend you check your Qoutemarks and check they are being opened and closed. Seems like you have one extra somewhere.

Comment: I tried this code and I couldn't reproduce the problem. Is this the right and complete code?

Comment: why ain't you using Json_encode. `echo json_encode($allUrls)`. You will get an javascript object that can be processed in JS code

Comment: Helloo, this is not the whole code of the page, this is just the part where i have the problem, i tried with quotemarks and theres is no extra ones :D

Comment: i can't use json_encode , im running this code on an old version of wamp, mean a very old version of php, and unfortunatly im not allowed to update it :/ (what !! )

Comment: Which PHP version? Also, maybe you should post the complete code..

Comment: Okay, added a little work around for json_encode. Of course you need to take care of special characters.

Answer (score 0):

Try rewriting your code like this:

```
include 'connect1.php';
$query = "SELECT URL FROM remontee_nlf ORDER BY URL ASC";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());
$counter = 0;
// write the values from the database into the javascript array

echo <<<HTML
<script type='text/javascript'>
this.styleListArray = new Array();
HTML;

$strLine = '';

if ($result) {
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $strLine.= "this.nameArray[" . $counter . "] = '" . $row['URL'] . ", " . $row['user_fname'] . "';"; 
        $counter += 1;
    }
}

echo $strLine;

echo("</script>");
```

Comment: Guess what, i still have the same problem :/ and here is what it shows on the page

Comment: this.styleListArray = new Array(); HTML; $strLine = ''; if ($result) { while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { $strLine.= "this.nameArray[" . $counter . "] = '" . $row['URL'] . ", " . $row['user_fname'] . "';"; $counter += 1; } } echo $strLine; echo(""); ?>

Answer (score 0):

First of all change your queries to use mysqli or pdo connections
secondly try following code

```
$sql = 'SELECT URL FROM remontee_nlf ORDER BY URL ASC';
$res = mysql_query($sql, $con);
$rows = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
    $rows[] = $row['URL'];

$str = implode('", "', $rows);
$data = '["'.trim($str).'"]';

echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
echo "var data = $data;";
echo 'console.log(data)';
echo '</script>';
```

check you console log.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You have `$result = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());;` change it to

```
$result = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());
```

Also make sure `$row['URL']` and `$row['user_fname']` are available.